# Open page in Django using <button> instead of <a>

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating my first Django app, and I am trying to open a template using a `button` tag. I have something like this here:

```
<button type="submit" onClick="window.location.href='details'">View</button>
```

In my `urls.py`, I have:

```
url(r'^details/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='details.html'), name=""),
```

I am not sure how to set the URL in `urls.py` to be able to access the `details.html` page. Currently, the page does not open. Does someone know how I can open it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `type="submit"`, sounds like you are using a form, right? If you do have a form, your url shouldn't be on the button but on the form `action` attribute.

You need to give your url a name, like:

```
url(r'^details/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='details.html'), name="details"),
```

Then your action would be:

```
action="{% url 'details' %}"
```

Read some resource online to learn [how to use a form action](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp).

<sub>I suggest you learn some html basics before jumping into django development, it would save your time wondering these kind of questions.</sub>

If you are not using a form, you might just need an `<a>` tag that looks like a button with css decoration. If you are using bootstrap, check out `.btn` class in the [documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#button-tags).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to avoid javascript and just make a really simple form:

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'details_page' %}">
    <button type="submit">View</button>
</form>
```

But you also need to name the route like so:

```
url(r'^details/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='details.html'), name="details_page")
```

Links are still preferrable though. It would be better to use some sort of CSS to make links and buttons look the same so you can use them interchangeably [like bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons).